# Big O notation calculating constant

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I have created a jaccard function where i know big O is O(n) how would i estimate the constant for my implementation and computer?

```
def jaccard(dict1,dict2):
   intersection={}
   for item in dict1.keys():
       if item in dict2.keys():
          intersection[item]=min(dict1[item],dict2[item])

   intersectiontot=maketotal(intersection)
   union = maketotal(dict1)+maketotal(dict2)-intersectiontot
   return intersectiontot/union
```

Comment: By timing the execution of your program?

Comment: i have timed my program im asking how i can get the constant from that.

Comment: Fit a line to your profiling data, if you know it's linear.

Comment: In time complexity theory "constant" is an abstract relative value. It can't be calculated. *Profiling* on the other hand delivers real values.

Comment: There is no need for the `.keys()` in `if item in dict2.keys()`. You’re also accessing the dictionary an unnecessary amount of times. Iterate over both the keys and values at once, and instead of checking if a key is in the dictionary only to access it again, just use `.get()` and assign the result to a variable.

Comment: The constant depends on exactly what is considered a single instruction or step. The point of big O is to hide the constant so that you don't need to worry about that definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a good estimate of the constant all you can do is do lots of runs (trying to keep the rest of your system quiet), with lots of different sized data sets, plot all of them on a scatter graph, and see if the points fit somewhere close to a straight line.

The slope of this line will give you the constant factor.

Large range of data sizes are required to ensure that you can see reasonable sized changes in execution time. Multiple runs at the same data size will help eliminate variability in measurements caused by other things on the system.

I am suprised your particular function is O(n) - I would have thought it would be O(nm) where n & m are the sizes of your two dictionary (unless one dictionary is always very small compared to the other).

Good luck.

---

A far more performant solution (without the multiple dictionary look ups and the repeaeted membership tests might be something like this :

```
 def jaccard(dict1,dict2):
     sentinel = object()
     intersection={}
     for key, value1 in dict1.items():
         value2 = dict2.get(key, sentinel)
         if value2 is not sentinel:
               intersection[item]=min(value1, value2)

     intersectiontot=maketotal(intersection)
     union = maketotal(dict1)+maketotal(dict2)-intersectiontot
     return intersectiontot/union
```

This function does a membership test in dict2 and a lookup at the same time, and removes the need for a separate lookup in dict1 after you have found the keys.

Depending on what maketotal does it might be possible to improve this even further.

Comment: Thank you for the clear response, I am running at worst possible scenario where both dictionaries are equal. would this then become O(n^2)?

Comment: I believe it would yes - nested loops tend to be O(nm) unless either n or m are very small compared to the other - in your case you will have O(nn) - i.e. O(n^2)

Comment: By doing ``item in dict2.keys()`` you are forcing a linear search across all the keys in dict2 - which is awful: 
if ``item in dict2`` is far better as it allows a hash based search of dict2 -  it is the search across dict2.keys() is what makes your code into an effective nested loop

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 no, only in Python 2. In Python 3, `.keys()` returns a view over the keys of the dict, which is a constant time operation and membership is likewise hash-based. It is redundant, though.

Comment: The biggest oversight has to be the iterating over the keys and checking membership only to index into the dict.

Comment: using dict.keys() to test for membership is a very bad idea - I agree.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you might be right - but using ``item in dict2.key()`` to test for membership is still pretty pointless in this case, especially when you just do ``item in dict1`` - creating a separate view just for membership testing is very bad practice I think.